# I have my main domain pointed to my main web host, and now I want to create a subdomain for Google Blogger

Tags: dns, subdomain, blogger, dns-servers

I have purchased domain from Domain India (www.example.com) and hosting at Cloud247.com and the main site (www.example.com) is hosted at Cloud247.com. But now I want to create a subdomain (xyz.example.com) for Google Blogger.

How can I do that?

At Domain India my account is showing "We are not manging your name server. bla bla"

So, let me know the details.

Comment: What are the nameservers that Domain India is showing? That will tell you which company is hosting your DNS, and therefore which account you will need to log in to to set up `A` and/or `CNAME` records for your subdomain.

Comment: Yes, Got it.. ! Its in Cloudhost....! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're asking this question in most cases I would respond with... just talk to your web host and domain registrar since your paying for a service and therefore they should offer you support and provide the 'exact' information, from where to click and what to input.

*But if you want to get hands-on or learn a little then...*

Currently, it sounds like you're pointing your domain to another party's nameserver, what this essentially means is the domain configuration file AKA Zone File is held with the 3rd party and therefore you need to update that file which is normally done by some type of dashboard.

If using cPanel/Plesk website hosting then you may be able to update the zone file via the cPanel or Plesk dashboard, but most shared hosting providers disable this option and therefore you would be required to contact your website host.

Alternatively, you can reset the nameservers back to your domain registrar and then point the A record & MX records to your website host and then setup a CNAME pointing to Blogger.